# Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call, in UIViewControllerRepresentable struct

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swiftui, nscoder

I'm trying to wrap a **UITabBarController** in a SwiftUI view using **UIViewControllerRepresentable** but ran into a problem that I haven't been able to solve for days. I've looked through every single possible thread and have tried all proposed solutions with no luck. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

**TabViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import ResearchKit
import CareKit
import SwiftUI

struct TabBarView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UITabBarController {
        let tabBarViewController = TabBarViewController()
        return tabBarViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UITabBarController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UITabBarController
    
    
}

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
  fileprivate let carePlanStoreManager = CarePlanStoreManager.sharedCarePlanStoreManager
  fileprivate let carePlanData: CarePlanData
  fileprivate var symptomTrackerViewController: OCKSymptomTrackerViewController? = nil
  fileprivate var insightsViewController: OCKInsightsViewController? = nil
  fileprivate var insightChart: OCKBarChart? = nil
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    carePlanData = CarePlanData(carePlanStore: carePlanStoreManager.store)

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    carePlanStoreManager.delegate = self
    carePlanStoreManager.updateInsights()

    let careCardStack = createCareCardStack()
    let symptomTrackerStack = createSymptomTrackerStack()
    let insightsStack = createInsightsStack()
    let connectStack = createConnectStack()
    
    self.viewControllers = [careCardStack,
                            symptomTrackerStack,
                            insightsStack,
                            connectStack]
    
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.systemTeal
    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
  }
```

I've also attached a screenshot that displays the exact error.[image]

Comment: Why are you surprised? You implemented `init(coder:)` and now that is the only initializer you have. When you say `TabBarViewController()` you are calling a different initializer, `init()`, and it doesn't exist. It's as if you had said to me "here, take these blue shoes" and then said "please give me the red shoes". What red shoes?

Comment: Haha I like the analogy and understand what you mean. I've tried initializing it and inserting all kinds of arguments with no luck. How can I insert the same initializer inside a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move everything into `init` as following (you don't need coder in this case)

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    fileprivate let carePlanData: CarePlanData
    fileprivate var symptomTrackerViewController: OCKSymptomTrackerViewController? = nil
    fileprivate var insightsViewController: OCKInsightsViewController? = nil
    fileprivate var insightChart: OCKBarChart? = nil
    
    fileprivate let carePlanStoreManager = CarePlanStoreManager.sharedCarePlanStoreManager
    init() {
        carePlanData = CarePlanData(carePlanStore: carePlanStoreManager.store)
        
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        
        carePlanStoreManager.delegate = self
        carePlanStoreManager.updateInsights()
        
        let careCardStack = createCareCardStack()
        let symptomTrackerStack = createSymptomTrackerStack()
        let insightsStack = createInsightsStack()
        let connectStack = createConnectStack()
        
        self.viewControllers = [careCardStack,
                                        symptomTrackerStack,
                                        insightsStack,
                                        connectStack]
        
        tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.systemTeal
        tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```